# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: c, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

As you can see below I have created a little program to concatenate 2 strings using C, as you may imagine this code doesn't work, I have already corrected it myself by using Array notation instead of pointers, and it works just fine, however I'm still not sure why is it that my code fails being almost a replica of my corrected code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void concatena(char *str1, char *str2){
 char *strAux;
 int mover;
 mover = 0;
 strAux = (char *)(malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)+2));
 *(strAux) = '\0';
 if(str1 == '\0')
    *strAux = '\0';
 else
     while(str1 != '\0'){
         *(strAux+mover++)=*(str1++);
     }
 if(str2 == '\0')
         *strAux = '\0';
 else
     while(str2 != '\0'){
         *(strAux+mover++)=*(str2++);
     }
 strAux='\0';
 str1=strAux;
 printf("%s", str1);
 free(strAux);
 }
```

I´m still a C beginner (And yes, I'm aware that there are libraries like string.h, I'm asking this for academic reasons) and I have been told that char pointers and arrays are the same thing, something that confuses the heck out of me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Always always always compile with all warnings, and don't ignore any warnings. That alone should alert you to most of your mistakes.

Comment: An array `degrades` to a pointer to the first element if you omit the index. If you have `char foo[10]` then `foo == &foo[0]`

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I did compile my program, got no warnings, except for the one that told me that my program was not responding. Obviously because the code itself is incorrect.

Comment: Would it kill you to write out the last two letters of "concatenate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem I see is with this section:

```
if(str2 == '\0')
    *strAux = '\0';
```

Just before this code, you've filled up `strAux` with the string from `str1`.
Then, if `str2` is empty, you suddenly put a null-terminator at the beginning of `strAux`, eliminating all the work you've done so far!

I think what you intend is:

```
if(*str2 == '\0')
     *(strAux+mover) = '\0';
```

Its the same thing again after your loop for `str2`, you have the code:

```
strAux='\0';
```

Again, this puts a null-terminator at the start of strAux, effectively ending the newly created string before it even gets started.

---

Here's how I'd re-write your code:

```
void concatena(char *str1, char *str2){
    char *strAux;
    int mover = 0;

    strAux = (char *)(malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)+1));  // Changed to +1, NOT +2
    *(strAux) = '\0';   // Start the string as (empty)

    while(*str1 != '\0'){   // Copy the first string over.
         *(strAux+mover++)=*(str1++);
    }

    while(*str2 != '\0'){   // Copy the second string over.
         *(strAux+mover++)=*(str2++);
    }

    *(strAux+mover)='\0';  // End the new, combined string.

    printf("%s", strAux);  // Show the results.
    free(strAux);
 }
```

Comment: Wow, you really made it look simple, excellent answer... I'm going back to the basics. Thank your for your help.

Comment: Thank you for being the one to put me over 10,000! :)

Comment: @abelenky:  Congratulations!  Enjoy all the new tools.

Answer (score 1):

Accepting the same constraints, here is how I would (re)write your code.  Unfortunately there is a specification shortcoming:  should the concatenation occur to the first string passed?  Or should a new string be created?  Here are both methods:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *concatena (const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
        char    *op, *newStr = (char*)malloc (strlen (str1) + strlen (str2) + 1);
        if (!newStr)
        {
                fprintf (stderr, "concatena: error allocating\n");
                return;
        }

        op = newStr;    // set up output pointer
        while (str1 && *str1)   // copy first string
                *op++ = *str1++;

        while (str2 && *str2)   // concatenate second string
                *op++ = *str2++;

        *op = '\000';           // add conventional NUL termination

        return newStr;
}


void concatenb (char *str1, const char *str2)
{
        char    *op;
        if (!str1)
        {
                fprintf (stderr, "concatenb: NULL string 1\n");
                return;
        }

        op = &str1 [strlen (str1)];     // set output pointer at trailing NUL

        while (str2 && *str2)   // concatenate second string
                *op++ = *str2++;

        *op = '\000';           // add conventional NUL termination
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strAux = (char *)(malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)+2));
```

**2** is not required, just **1** is sufficient for the termination character.

```
*(strAux) = '\0';
```

This should be happening only at the end of all your computation. Not in between the concatenation i.e.,

```
while(*str1 != '\0'){  // This loops copies the first string
    // ^ Notice that you need to dereference to check for the termination character.
     *(strAux+mover++)=*(str1++);
}
while(*str2 != '\0'){  // This loop copies the second string
     *(strAux+mover++)=*(str2++);
}
// Finally adding termination character
*(strAux+mover) = '\0'; // since with mover you are keeping track of locations.
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount of errors in your code is disheartening. You should probably pick up a good C book and start over.

First off, there's a library function that you can use to concatenate strings:

```
const unsigned int len = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1;
char * dst = malloc(len);
strncat(dst, str1, len);
strncat(dst, str2, len);
```

Now, if you insist on doing it manually, you have to get pointers and dereferencing right:

```
char * d = dst;
while (*str1 != 0) *dst++ = *str1++;
while (*str2 != 0) *dst++ = *str2++;
*dst = 0;
// d now points to the beginning of the concatenated string
```

The two loops check if the current character in the input string is nonzero, and if so, then they copy that character to the current character in the output string, and then both input and output pointer are advanced. (This is all done in one wash by use of the postfix `++` operator.) Finally, the last character is set to zero to create a new null-terminator.

In the process we modified all three pointers `dst`, `str1` and `str2`. The latter two came in as input function arguments by copy, so that's fine. For returning the concatenated string we made a copy of `dst` before the loop, which we can return in the end.

Comment: I think the OP was pretty clear that he didn't want to use the built-in functions, but wanted to write his own for learning purposes.

While your version is extremely compact, I don't blame a newbie for having trouble following it, and wanting to write a more explicit, if more verbose version.

Comment: The fact that you tell anyone new to use `strcat` rather than `strncat` is disheartening. ;)

Comment: @Abelenky: Doing things by hand for understanding is always good, but a sound grasp on pointers and dereferencing is a must before any such attempt. Anyway, I've added some explanation of the code -- I think the conciseness actually works in favour of clarity in this case. Imagine, I could have said `while(*str1)` :-)

Comment: @Brioan: touche :-) I wanted to save the extra line for the lenght. Maybe that was overly stingy. Though I'm sure there'll be some zealots who want the extra bit of performance, given that we just used `strlen` in the line above.

Comment: Why are all the answers here being downvoted? @abelenky You got a +1 from me too, but I think Kerrek's version with incrementing a pointer, rather than using an index variable is a lot easier to understand.

Comment: I would not recommend either `strcat` or `strncat`. The right library call, if OP did not want to write this himself, is `snprintf(dest, dest_size, "%s%s", str1, str2);` -- it's all one line, and it's 100% safe.

Comment: My solution is full of errors I understand that, however I have been given the assignment of using only methods that I can create so... It's kind of difficult to  optimize the code, let alone getting it right in the first try, thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: @Praetorian I downvoted abelenkys answer because it was incorrect before he edited it. He had `(str1 == '\0')` instead of `(*str1 == '\0')`. I removed my downvote after he edited it.